# Web Audio API split mono to stereo

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Lets say I have a source node that's connected to the destination node.
Even if the audio is mono, I want to be able to control each ear's volume independently, like I can do when I have stereo audio with splitter and merger node.

Already tried to use splitter and merger nodes on the mono source node, but right channel comes out empty.

example for stereo:

```js
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);
var gainNodeL = audioCtx.createGain();
var gainNodeR = audioCtx.createGain();
var splitter = audioCtx.createChannelSplitter(2);
var merger = audioCtx.createChannelMerger(2);

source.connect(splitter);
splitter.connect(gainNodeL, 0);
splitter.connect(gainNodeR, 1);

gainNodeL.connect(merger, 0, 0);
gainNodeR.connect(merger, 0, 1);

merger.connect(audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination());
```

When I do this with mono audio, the right channel comes out empty.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a signal is only mono (or in other words its channelCount is 1) the ChannelSplitterNode is not necessary. I modified the example a bit. It does now split the mono signal of an Oscillator.

```
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
var gainNodeL = audioCtx.createGain();
var gainNodeR = audioCtx.createGain();
var merger = audioCtx.createChannelMerger(2);

oscillator.connect(gainNodeL);
oscillator.connect(gainNodeR);

gainNodeL.connect(merger, 0, 0);
gainNodeR.connect(merger, 0, 1);

merger.connect(audioCtx.destination);

oscillator.start();

function left () {
    gainNodeL.gain.value = 1;
    gainNodeR.gain.value = 0;
}

function right () {
    gainNodeL.gain.value = 0;
    gainNodeR.gain.value = 1;
}

function center () {
    gainNodeL.gain.value = 1;
    gainNodeR.gain.value = 1;
}
```

Comment: It does work with oscillator node, but source node cant connect to 2 nodes, it throws an exception

Comment: Hi @AlonDayan, which error do you get? Replacing the oscillator with a MediaElementSourceNode works for me in Firefox and Chrome. In theory it should be okay to connect a node to as many other nodes as you want.