# javascript new audioContext mono to Stereo not wordking

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I need to convert the mp3 files I play in a project from mono to stereo with the web audio api. But do this a1 = new Audio(`/1.mp3`); I can't with. My entire system is based on this build. Converting all the sounds playing on the page to stereo or new Audio(`/1.mp3`); Is there a way to convert a sound created with .

```js
var a1 = new Audio(`/1.mp3`);

a1.volume = .5;
a1.play()
```

I am using a simple code structure as above.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54990085/15929287
I couldn't adapt the above answer for myself. In no way can I convert the sound I created with new audio() to stereo. In the example in the link, the oscillator is also added. I'm just trying to do something where I can adjust the mono/stereo setting. I need your help.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the answer that you linked. I would be happy to help but I'm not sure if I understand your question. What did you do to connect the audio element to an `AudioContext` and what exactly didn't work?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. Your answer is an excellent answer. My problem is applying it on the audio I created with new Audio() instead of doing it with AudioContext. I've found examples made with AudioContext but not one with new Audio(). Is this possible? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54990085/15929287) assumes the mono audio source is an oscillator created with the Web Audio API but it is also possible to use an audio element as the source by using a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`.

The audio graph would then need to be wired up like this:

```
const audio = new Audio('/1.mp3');
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
const gainNodeL = audioCtx.createGain();
const gainNodeR = audioCtx.createGain();
const merger = audioCtx.createChannelMerger(2);

source.connect(gainNodeL);
source.connect(gainNodeR);

gainNodeL.connect(merger, 0, 0);
gainNodeR.connect(merger, 0, 1);

merger.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Please note that it's probably still necessary to call `resume()` on the `AudioContext` in response to a user gesture to make sure the `AudioContext` is running.

Comment: thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I think this can be simplified slightly by using a single gain node and setting the gain.ChannelCountMode = 'explicit' and gain.channelCount = 2.  This means the input is mixed to 2 channels (stereo), so your mono input is mixed to stereo, which is then the output of the gain node.

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. The linked question/answer was also about how to level each channel independently. But if that's not necessary as single `GainNode` should work, too.